# How to add local git user to the vagrant machine?

Tags: git, shell, vagrant, homestead, vagrant-provision

I'm provisioning laravel homestead (which is wrapper for vagrant). And I want to run provision script that will add local machine git user as a vagrant git user.
But the problem I've found is, I can't access local env inside this shell script since it runs in the vagrant box.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a shell provisioning script, you can use the [`env`](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/shell.html#env) options.

```
box.vm.provision :shell do |s|
  s.env = {VM_VAR:ENV['HOST_VAR']}
  s.path = 'scripts/bootstrap.sh'
end
```

in the VM, your script will be able to access `VM_VAR` environment variable